# Filter multiple scenario in single statement without multiple condition

Tags: java

```
        List<EmployeeDTO> employeeList = dto.getEmployeeList();

        EmployeeDTO employeeListDetails = employeeList.stream().filter(item -> "C".equals(item.getYearInd())).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (Objects.nonNull(employeeListDetails)) {
            return employeeListDetails.geId();
        }

        employeeListDetails = employeeList.stream().filter(item -> "F".equals(item.getYearInd())).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (Objects.nonNull(employeeListDetails)) {
            return employeeListDetails.geId();
        }

        employeeListDetails = employeeList.stream().filter(item -> "P".equals(item.getYearInd())).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (Objects.nonNull(employeeListDetails)) {
            return employeeListDetails.geId();
        }

        employeeListDetails = employeeList.stream().filter(item -> "M".equals(item.getYearInd())).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (Objects.nonNull(employeeListDetails)) {
            return employeeListDetails.geId();
        }
```

Above code working fine. What I have tried to do in above code filter data based on some condition if data not found then again tried to filter with some other data. Above code working fine.

But is there any other better way ro do this like without multiple if. In single statement is it possible to take care all the condition? Like if data not found in first condition then do another filer in same like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop:

```java
List<EmployeeDTO> employeeList = dto.getEmployeeList();

EmployeeDTO employeeListDetails;
final String[] years = new String[] { "C", "F", "P", "M" };
for (int i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    final String year = years[i];
    employeeListDetails =
        employeeList
            .stream()
            .filter(item -> year.equals(item.getYearInd()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

    if (Objects.nonNull(employeeListDetails)) {
        return employeeListDetails.geId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
EmployeeDTO employeeListDetails = Stream.of("C", "F", "P", "M")
    .flatMap(yearInd -> employeeList.stream()
        .filter(employee -> yearInd.equals(employee.getYearInd())))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
if (Objects.nonNull(employeeListDetails)) {
    return employeeListDetails.geId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, there is another way. You could do this as follows.

First, we're going to get a `TreeMap` with the mapping `yearInd => employeeId`.

```java
TreeMap<String, Long> map = employees.stream()
    .filter(employee -> "CFPM".contains(employee.yearInd()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::yearInd, Employee::id, (a, b) -> a, () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(str -> {
        int pos = "CFPM".indexOf(str);
        return (pos == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : pos + Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }))));
```

What happens here, is as follows:

- Stream over the employees.
- Filter out yearInds other than C, F, P and M.
- Collect into a map as follows:

  - As key, select the yearInd.
  - As value, select the employee id.
  - As merge function (if two keys are the same, which is not possible with a map), pick the first one.
  - Use a `TreeMap` as implementation. A `TreeMap` is a map whose keys are sorted by some given `Comparator`. The Comparator used below simply puts C first, then F, then P, then M and then the remaining characters. Note that the comparator function is a slightly silly one.

Then we have a `TreeMap`. We just need to select the first element, with `map.firstEntry()`. If it's not `null`, we only need to get the value:

```java
Long result = map.firstEntry() != null ? map.firstEntry().getValue() : null;
```

(No idea why there is no `firstValue()` method.)

#### Example

```java
record Employee(long id, String name, String yearInd) { }
```

```java
List<Employee> employees = List.of(
    new Employee(1, "David", "D"),
    new Employee(4, "Fauntleroy", "F"),
    new Employee(6, "Monica", "M"),
    new Employee(7, "Nicole", "N"),
    new Employee(2, "Caroline", "C"),
    new Employee(3, "Chris", "C"),
    new Employee(5, "Mike", "M")
);
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all at once and then sort the result before picking the first one.
I haven't tested that, but it should be something like:

```
EmployeeDTO employeeListDetails = employeeList.stream()
    .filter(item -> {
        return "C".equals(item.getYearInd()) ||
               "F".equals(item.getYearInd()) ||
               "P".equals(item.getYearInd()) ||
               "M".equals(item.getYearInd());
    })
    .sorted((item1, item2) -> {
        if(("P".equals(item1.getYearInd()) && "M".equals(item2.getYearInd()))
            || ("M".equals(item1.getYearInd()) && "P".equals(item2.getYearInd()))){
            return item2.getYearInd().compareTo(item1.getYearInd());
        } else {
            return item1.getYearInd().compareTo(item2.getYearInd());
        }
    })
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```